# Cannot boot Ubuntu 16..04

Tags: boot, 16.04, services

I am having this issue on images when I boot, many services fail to start and I am unable to have the login screen.

[image: Here is the image of the screen.]

Transcribed text:

```
See 'systemctl status systemd-logind.service' for details.
[FAILED] Failed to start Bluetooth service.
See 'systemctl status bluetooth.service' for details.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: This starts a set of rethinkdb server instances.
[  OK  ] Started System Logging Service.
[  OK  ] Started Save/Restore Sound Card State.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: VirtualBox Linux Additions.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: daemon to balance interrupts for SMP systems.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: This services starts and stops the USB Arbitrator
[FAILED] Failed to start Thermal Daemon Service.
See 'systemctl status thermald.service' for details.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB.
[  OK  ] Started Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system cha
[FAILED] Failed to start Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
See 'systemctl status avahi-daemon.service' for details.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.
[  OK  ] Started USB_ModeSwitch_2-1.2:1.0.
[FAILED] Failed to start Accounts Service.
See 'systemctl status accounts-daemon.service' for details.
[FAILED] Failed to start Modem Manager.
See 'systemctl status ModemManager.service' for details.
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Manager.
See 'systemctl status NetworkManager.service' for details.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Network Manager Wait Online.
```

Comment: What did you do before you ended up like this?

Comment: Just went out of batterie, that was all.